# Make the cart automatically add quantity to 0 to cart page in WooCommcerce

Tags: cart, product-quantity

I need my cart page to automatically add products to it when user visits the cart page with quantity 0, I tried to change it by:

I tried code 1 and code 2 with some variations but when I click on update cart the quantity get again to zero. For that product, although total remains the same.
What it should is the cart items wit zero quantities should not be removed when I update the cart and the quantity of that product which I changes from 0 to 1 should be get to 1.

## Code 1

```
function add_product_to_cart_new() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = array(2595,2594,1404,2650,1410,2652); //replace with your own product id
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                
                if (in_array($_product->get_id(), $product_id))
                //if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
             //if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
              
                    foreach($product_id as $ids ){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $ids);
                    }
        } else {
             //if no products in cart, add it
                    foreach($product_id as $ids ){
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $ids);
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

And then below code (input_value) to make it zero on cart page.

## Code 2

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    
    //if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
     if(  is_cart() ){
        $args['input_value']    = 0;    // Starting value (we only want to affect  cart page)
     }
    //}
    $args['max_value']  = 80;   // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 0;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 1;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}
```

Expected results like in this:
http://www.ecotechlube.com/cart/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but it is the only way I have found to do this.

First of all, you need to add product to cart with a magic small quantity, like this:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 0.00000001);
```

Then you need to make checks in cart and checkout templates like this:

```
if($cart_item['quantity'] == 0.00000001) $cart_item['quantity'] = 0;
```